# Complex Joins and Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need some help with a query I need to write

Retrieve the first and last names of employees who work on projects which are not controlled by their departments. Also show the names of the projects, the employee's department number, and the number of the project's controlling department. (All of this should be shown in the same result table.) Show results in ascending alpha order (by last name and then first name and then
project name).

tables:

```
Employee(Fname,Lname,SSN,DepartNum)
Department(Dname,Dnumber)
Project(Pname,Pnumber,DepNum)
WorksOn(EmpSSN,ProjNum)
```

Column Headings of the query: Fname,Lname,Pname,E_DNUM,P_DNUM

```
SELECT Fname,Lname,Project.Pname,(Employee.DepartNum) AS E_DNUM (Project.DepNum) AS P_DNUM
FROM Department,
    (SELECT *
    FROM Employee
    LEFT JOIN WorksOn
      LEFT JOIN Project
      ON Project.Pnumber = WorksOn.Pnum
    ON Employee.SSN = WorksOn.ESSN)
WHERE Project.DepNum = Department.Dnumber
AND Employee.DepartNum <> Department.Dnumber;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not missing something you could join all the tables and apply a condition `Employee.DepartNum <> Project.DepNum` to get the results you want:

```
select Fname,Lname,Pname, Employee.DepartNum E_DNUM,Project.DepNum P_DNUM
from Employee
join WorksOn on WorksOn.EmpSSN = Employee.SSN
join Project on WorksOn.ProjNum = Project.Pnumber
join Department on Project.DepNum = Department.Dnumber
where Employee.DepartNum <> Project.DepNum
```